# How can I find the index of the n-th sequential value in a list that meets some criteria?

Tags: python, list, indexing, sequential

I am trying to find the index of the third sequential value in a list that is greater than a certain number. For instance in the example below, I'd like to identify the index where there are 3 values greater than 1, which would return the index at value 1.4. With the code I've tried below, I am retrieving the 1.3 value.

I have tried to use enumerate, but this returns the 3rd index total, instead of the 3rd sequential value.

Is there a way to identify the sequential third value with this condition of greater than 1?

```
listtest = [0.56, 1.25, 0.8, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2, 1.6]
indexBDF = [i for i, n in enumerate(listtest) if n >= 1 ][2]
print(listtest[indexBDF])
```

The above code returns 1.3 since it's the third value greater than 1. I'd like for the code to return 1.4, since it's the third value in a row greater than 1.

Comment: Have you tried writing a normal `for` loop? If there is a value greater than 1 you increment a counter, otherwise you reset it to 0. If the counter reaches 3, you return the current loop index.

Comment: Alternatively, you need to take the two previous values into account for each value in the list.

Comment: "greater" or `>=`? Index or value? What do you really want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a traditional `for` loop to solve this problem:

```
listtest = [0.56, 1.25, 0.8, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2, 1.6]

occurrences = 0

for index,elem in enumerate(listtest):
    if elem > 1:
        occurrences += 1
                 
        if occurrences == 3:
            print("Element =", elem)
            print("Index =", index)
            occurrences = 0

    else:
        occurrences = 0
```

Output:

```
Element = 1.4
Index = 5
```

You can try this if you want to print all possible combinations:

```
listtest = [0.56, 1.25, 0.8, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2, 1.6]

for index,num in enumerate(listtest):
    if index+3 < len(listtest) + 1:
        num_lst = listtest[index:index+3]
        if all(num > 1 for num in num_lst):
            print("Element =",num_lst[-1],", Index =", index+2)
```

Output:

```
Element = 1.4 , Index = 5
Element = 2 , Index = 6
Element = 1.6 , Index = 7
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! I had to include a break statement at the end of the second if statement, but definitely got the result I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat ugly version using `itertools`:

```
>>> next(i
         for k, g in groupby(enumerate(listtest), lambda x: x[1] >= 1)
         if k
         for i, _ in islice(g, 2, None))
5
```

This finds groups of consecutive items fulfilling the criterion, and then tries to read the third item of the group. First one there is will be the result.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `zip()`, `enumerate()`, `all()`, and a for loop to analyze the values as a 3-tuple:

```
listtest = [0.56, 1.25, 0.8, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2, 1.6]

for idx, values in enumerate(zip(listtest, listtest[1:], listtest[2:]), start=2):
    if all(val > 1 for val in values):
        print(f'found 3 sequential values {values} > 1 at index: {idx}')
        break
```

Output:

```
found 3 sequential values (1.2, 1.3, 1.4) > 1 at index: 5
```

Answer (score 1):

This implementation provides a generic way to find the nth consecutive element that satisfies some arbitrary filter criteria and will work on lists containing any data type.

```python
def nth_seq_item_index(item_list: list, n: int, filter: callable):
    """The nth item `n` starts at 1 (i.e. 1st sequential item). The `filter` 
    is a function returning True or False for an item in the list."""
    if n < 1:
        raise ValueError("n must be greater than 0")
    consec_count = 0
    for index, item in enumerate(item_list):
        if filter(item):
            consec_count += 1
        else:
            consec_count = 0
        if consec_count == n:
            return index
    return None


listtest = [0.56, 1.25, 0.8, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2, 1.6]
indexBDF = nth_seq_item_index(listtest, n=3, filter=lambda i: i >= 1)

print(listtest[indexBDF])
```

#### Output

```
1.4
```